# Is there any replacement of seam Renderer(email) in CDI?

Tags: java, email, jsf, cdi

I'm working on migration of application from seam to CDI and need help for following-

1. As in seam we use Renderer for sending mails, is there and replacement for this in CDI.
2. In Seam we use following tags for composing mails :

   1. message
   2. to
   3. cc
   4. from

Is there any replacement for these tags

Comment: Nope. Nope. Nope. Nope

Comment: Why are you not interested in using the `javax.mail` API which in essence, is portable across all major Java applications?